# select next 2 digits starts with XXX but not XXX

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find `about` text and width value(so: `50%`). To select `50%` with regex I have to add `width="` inside the regex. So, `width="\d{2}%` will select `width="50%` but I need to select only `50%` in the first one.

In the second one, I have to select(find) only `about` text not `<td>about`.

```
<tr>
    <td width="50%">about</td>
```

1. Select the width value with percentage(search with "width" word but not select "width").
2. Select only "about" string

Comment: Regex isnt the answer for this problem

Comment: The question is not clear at all, could you give more details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you will find out that using regular expressions to parse HTML is near impossible.

But the basic reg exps would be:

```
var reWidth = /width="(\d{1,3}%)"/i;
var reCellText = /<td[^>]?>([^<]*)/i;
```

[EDIT]

Guessing by your comment below, you do not understand capture groups.

```
var str = '<td width="25%">';
var myMatch = str.match(reWidth);
if(myMatch){
    alert( myMatch[1] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it selects "width" with numbers. I want to remove "width" word in result. And reCellText is also selection `<td>about` .

Comment: then replace 'width' with nothing.

Comment: I updated my answer since you do not seem to know about capture groups.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for look behinds, but unfortunately **Javascript does not support look behinds.**

This would look like

```
(?<=width=")\d+
```

and would match only the digits.

I think you should explain more what you want to achieve (why you want to do this) to get an appropriate answer. I am not sure if regex is the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

one shot for your two requirements. tested with grep:

```
kent$  echo '<td width="50%">about</td>'|grep -oP '(?<=width=")\d+%|(?<=>)[^<>]*(?=<)'
50%
about

(?<=width=")\d+%          ->%number after width="
|                         ->or
(?<=>)[^<>]*(?=<)         -> anything(besides < and >) between > and <
```

Comment: Could you please explain this RegEx?

Comment: i updated the answer with explanation to get better code format. Well I don't know js doesn't support look behinds. not familiar with js.